# Unable to send emails from deployed NodeJS app using Brevo (previously sendinblue)

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer, sendinblue

I am using `Brevo (previously Sendinblue)` for sending transactional emails like verification, password-reset, etc.
I deployed my `NodeJS` app on `cyclic`. All the other functionalities are working fine except the emails.

The emails were working great in the localhost, but as soon as I deployed my app they aren't working anymore. Most probably the problem is with Brevo (previously Sendinblue) according to me. Adding the relevant code below.

`sendEmail.js`

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const sendEmail = async (email, subject, text) => {
  try {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "SendinBlue",
      auth: {
        user: process.env.SIB_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.SIB_PASS,
      },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.SIB_EMAIL,
      to: email,
      subject: subject,
      html: text,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Email sent:", info.response);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

`/forgot-password`

```
const forgotPassword = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ success: true, message: "User not found" });
    }
    const resetToken = uuid();
    user.reset_token = resetToken;
    user.reset_token_expiry = Date.now() + 3600000; //1 hour

    await user.save();

    const resetLink = `${process.env.FRONTEND_URI}/reset-password?resetToken=${resetToken}`;

    const emailContent = `
    <p>Click on the link below to reset your password</p>
    <a href=${resetLink}>${resetLink}</a>
    <br>
    <h5>Team Sukoon</h5>
    `;

    sendEmail(email, "Sukoon: Reset your password", emailContent);
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Email sent successfully" });
  } catch {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "server error" });
  }
};
```

When I check `cyclic` logs there are no errors and I get a response code 200.